pytest decorators : test_get_run_time() missing 1 required positional argument: 'capfd'
I want to test a functions print output. But even though i have imported pytest it doesnt work
import pytest 
import io

from time import sleep

import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")))
from decorators import get_time, init_logger

init_logger(True)

@get_time
def test_get_run_time(capfd):
    sleep(1.5)
    capture = capfd.readouterr()

i searched in the internet and could not how to solve this


capfd is a pytest fixture, and it needs to be included as an argument in your test function to work properly.

Use assertions to check if the output is what you expect.
      def test_get_run_time(capfd):
         sleep(1.5)

         capture = capfd.readouterr()

         assert "Testing output" in capture.out


modify the decorator and then import in the main file using from decorators import get_time
 import time

 def get_time(func):
     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         start_time = time.process_time()    
         result = func(*args, **kwargs)     
         end_time = time.process_time()      
         print(f"Function {func.__name__} took {end_time - start_time:.4f} CPU seconds")
         return result                       
     return wrapper  




well the problem is i use a decorator so it doesnt work
    
        start_time: float = perf_counter()
>       result: any = func(*args, **kwargs)
E       TypeError: test_get_run_time() missing 1 required positional argument: 'capfd'```

then you have to modify the decorator to accept arbitrary arguments and keyword arguments.

use the different file to modify your decorator then import the file to pass capfd as an argument
